# software development, v-model through examples, step by step?

Tags: testing, v-model

I'm currently studying software development.
I would like to understand the V-model, but I can't find an example anywhere that describes its process step by step.
Could you help me?
I would need a specific example with details about the development of a simple application and sample documents.
Thank you for your help!

(I've watched many videos and read blog posts, but I couldn't find any examples.)
I also know that the agile method should be used, but I would like to understand it.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When doing research like this, it helps to track down the original papers or books published. In this case, if you start with the Wikipedia article for the Vee model:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/V-model_(software_development)

and then look at the references, you'll see a link to a paper :

https://web.archive.org/web/20030420130303/http://www.incose.org/sfbac/welcome/fcb-csm.pdf

that has detailed examples.

Two final thoughts:

- software methodologies are guidelines; you're unlikely to find step-by-step breakdowns, they're vague because they discuss processes that happen over weeks or months between whole teams, departments, and companies
- Agile is mostly a reaction *against* this kind of methodology.